# Using multiple view directories in Koa

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, koa

I am creating a web app in a modular way using NodeJS & Koa-views, I have this folder structure:

```
A/
routes/
models/
views/

B/
routes/
models/
views/
```

and then in my Index.js I have:

```js
    app.use(views(`${__dirname}/A/views`, { extension: 'handlebars' }, {map: { handlebars: 'handlebars' }}))
```

I want to use the views from directory B aswell, so the code becomes:

```js
    app.use(views(`${__dirname}/A/views`, { extension: 'handlebars' }, {map: { handlebars: 'handlebars' }}))
    app.use(views(`${__dirname}/B/views`, { extension: 'handlebars' }, {map: { handlebars: 'handlebars' }}))
```

However I get an error stating it can't find A/B/views, (I understand it is executing the first views and thinking it will find the view for B in there), so is there a way to use multiple view folders?

(Express uses app.set(views, [dir1, dir2 ... ] but I can't figure out how to implement this in Koa)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked source code, it does not seems possible with `koa-views` package.

As a quick and dirty workaround you can try to setup middleware like this:

```js
app.use(views(__dirname, { extension: 'handlebars' }, {map: { handlebars: 'handlebars' }}))
```

And then call render method with relative path to actual template:

```js
await ctx.render('B/views/templateName');
```

But be aware that it might be a bad solution, as basically you expose other non-view folders as well.